# Kohana 3.3 - pagination missing action parametr

Tags: pagination, kohana, render

Bootstap:

```
Route::set('user', 'user/<username>(/<action>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'user',
    'username' => '\d+',
));
```

Controller User:

```
public function action_cget(){
        $page_num = @$_GET['page']? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $per_page = 5;
        $offset = ($page_num - 1) * $per_page;
        $username = $this->request->param('username'); 

        $session = Session::instance();
        $mUser = Model::factory('User');
        $id = $mUser->getID($username);
        $view = View::factory('index');

        $total = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` IN('.$ids.')')->execute()->as_array();

        $q = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` IN('.$ids.') LIMIT '.$per_page.' OFFSET '.$offset)->execute()->as_array();
        $pagination = Pagination::factory(array(
            'total_items' => count($total),
            'current_page' => array('source' => 'query_string', 'key' => 'page'),
            'items_per_page' => $per_page,
            'view' => 'pagination/basic'));



        $view->content = View::factory('user/cget');
        $view->content->comments = $q;
        $view->content->pagi = $pagination;
        $this->response->body($view);
```

(i deleted more of code)

All is OK, but pagination render bad - render without action.

I'm on the page http://mysite.com/user/NetJaro/cget

and pagination render links like http://mysite.com/user/NetJaro?page=2 (there is no action, like "cget").

Somebody can help me? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by making some general fixes.

First of all Kohana is a `HMVC` framework. Which means that any `Request` can call any number of 'subrequests'. Your code is not `HMVC`-friendly. Let's say you wish to call this action as a subrequest in the correct way.

```
 echo Request::Factory('user/NetJaro/cget')
      ->query(array('some' => 'some-query-parameters', ...))
      ->execute();
```

This won't work! Even if you put the query parameters in the request! That is because of this line, which uses the superglobal, which is never set in a subrequest:

```
$page_num = @$_GET['page']? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

It should be the following, which does exactly the same thing AND is subrequest friendly.

```
$page_num = Arr::get($this->request->query(), 'page', 1);
```

Next I took a look at your route. And noticed this regex for the username `'username' => '\d+',`. You only allow numbers? Shouldn't that be `[a-zA-Z0-9]` To allow all regular characters which a username may constist of?

Then, we come to the following lines:

```
$mUser = Model::factory('User');
$id = $mUser->getID($username);
```

If I am correct you create a user object, then get the ID seperately. Why don't you use:

```
$user = ORM::factory('User', array('username' => $username));
$user_id = $user->id;
```

To query your database for a user with that username.

Next we come to some content generation.

```
$total = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` IN('.$ids.')')->execute()->as_array();
```

Where does `$ids` come from? And why don't you use ORM?

```
$total = ORM::factory('Comment')->where('post_id', 'IN', $ids)->count_all();
```

Same thing for the next query.

```
$q = ORM::factory('Comment')
    ->where('post_id', 'IN', $ids)
    ->limit($per_page)
    ->offset($offset)
    ->find_all();
```

Now you don't have to worry about SQL injection or whatever at all. And the models you create are ORM models giving you all the functions you need from that model!

And last, we come to your error. This is probably because no action is echo'd there. Wherever you echo those urls add a: `<?php echo Request::$initial->action(); ?>`. But I can't see the code of the pagination. So I can't know for sure.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks so much for yours advice.

I use <?php echo Request::$initial->action(); ?> and it's show me my action.

In /users/NetJaro/cwrite it's show me "cwrite", so it's OK.

I use a Pagination from Kohana 3.3 on https://github.com/shadowhand/pagination

Comment: No.

When I use Pagination and render it on the site http://site.com/user/NetJaro/cwrite pagination render the link without action (http://site.com/user/NetJaro/?page=2).

But the <?php echo Request::$initial->action(); ?> shows the action corret.

Comment: Could you include the code of the pagination view in your question? Nevermind, it's in the github codebase.